# How to set Accessibility focus to button programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility

In iOS, how to set accessibility focus to a button through programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean making a button active?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via following notifications:

`UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification`

or

`UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification`

E.g.

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, yourElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

@ClemensL response works great.
Here is a Swift 5 version:

```
func setAccessibilityFocus() {
    UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.layoutChanged, argument: self)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set focus to any UI element by using the following snippet.

UIAccessibility.setFocusTo(your-UI-element)