# Set accessibility order for the element in the Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have tried to set the **accessibility** reading order in the **voiceover** when we **swipe right /left** .But i don't know how to set that in the **xamarin IOS**.

I have also want to know that how to move the focus to the particular element .

Comment: Refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347350/xamarin-ios-how-can-we-set-accessibility-focus-to-a-button-programatically

Comment: I have already refered but this is for the notification of the layout change or somewhat works with screen changed.